# Github Action Runner With Kotlin Gradle Fail

Tags: java, kotlin, unit-testing, gradle, github-actions

I am trying to use a github action runner to run a test in my Kotlin project.

It's part of a gradle springboot project (a simple API microservice).
That said, the test is just a standalone 'hello world' type unit test which lives in it's own module and of course has no problems when run locally (I'm using a custom gradle task to run it)!

Here is my workflow yaml file -

```
name: Kotlin CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: 17
          distribution: 'adopt'
      - name: Run Simple Unit Test 
        run: ./gradlew simple-unit-test--info
        env:
          GRADLE_OPTS: -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g"
```

The result of github action running the test is -

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
```

So it appears that the test isn't even being run, and the gradle daemon explodes before it even gets that far!

However, if I change the gradle task from `simple-unit-test` to `compileKotlin` (which will compile the code of my springboot api) it works with no trouble at all.

Does anybody have some direction for me? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I've tried -

- running my gradle task with no caching
- running gradle task with no daemon
- checked resources of self-hosted runner (these appear to be sufficient - see comment below)
- tried various different gradle/java versions

Comment: You're running the GitHub action on a self-hosted instance. Can you provide more details about that? What are the system specs? Does it report any problems? Have you tried using a GitHub runner, like `ubuntu-latest`?

Comment: It is an ubuntu instance, with 30GB of memory and x4 cpus. It reports no problems and appears to have sufficient resources for the build so far (I've monitored it with top). I'm using a self-hosted runner as it needs access to to a secure space behind a VPN, so unfortunately using a github runner isn't an option.

Comment: I did try running my test on a standard github `ubuntu-latest` instance and it was allowed to run, there was no issue with the gradle runner. This is odd as the github runner has less memory/cpu resource than my self-hosted runner.